# Display dropbox status

Tags: mode-line, shell-command, mode-line-format

I would like my emacs to call

`dropbox status`

every 30 seconds and display whether Dropbox is up-to-date at the bottom of the buffer (where info such as the line-number and file name is).

How could I do this?

EDIT to add:

On my linux (with dropbox installed), the command line `dropbox status` returns the Dropbox status:

`$ dropbox status
Up to date`

Unfortunately it seems like this doesn't work on OSX (https://superuser.com/questions/678925/using-dropbox-from-the-command-line-on-osx).

Comment: Have not tried anything so far and not very familiar with Emacs Lisp. Was actually hoping this problem might have simple enough recipe for me to learn a little Emacs Lisp through implementing the solution (as that is my preferred learning style). However from your comments it sounds like I probably need more Emacs Lisp background before approaching this problem.

Comment: You should scour the internet to see if DropBox status can be achieved with a command-line from the terminal.  If your research reveals that it can be done from the terminal, then revise/edit your question by posting a recipe of how to do that.  If you are using OSX, then also look for an applescript.  Then, the majority of readers of this forum can turn that command-line recipe or applescript into Lisp using things like `start-process` or `do-applescript`.

Comment: I added a +1 because the original poster selected good tags for this project.  The O.P. just needed a direction to go in -- i.e., find a command-line recipe or applescript that can obtain dropbox status, and from there the question should be how to turn it into Lisp and incorporate the result into the `mode-line-format`.

Comment: @lawlist thank you for the upvote. I edited the question to partially address your comment. I am starting to read up a little on Emacs Lisp so in future I may add an edit with more specific Emacs Lisp question/direction.

Comment: When you get a chance, please evaluate:  `(shell-command-to-string "dropbox status")` and see if it produces a result in the `*Messages*` buffer.  And, if so, whether there is a trailing "\n" for new line -- which would need to be programmatically removed in the next step . . . .  Here is what I am using to test this, because I'm on OSX not Linux -- I'm just using the command-line for getting the date when in the terminal:  `(replace-regexp-in-string "\n$" "" (shell-command-to-string "date"))`  The next step will be to . . .

Comment: @lawlist I get `"Up to date\n"` (with trailing newline). Also got a `"Syncing \"file.lyx~\"\nDownloading \"file.lyx~\"...\n"` when I called the same command, while file.lyx was being updated in my Dropbox (notice the `\n` in the middle of the latter output).

Comment: Before we play with a `run-with-timer` and the `mode-line-format`, you should decide how you want to handle your status string (which may need truncation so that it doesn't fill up your mode-line, or it may need something simpler like one of two possibilities -- "**syncing**" and "**updated**", depending upon the result of `dropbox status`).  Here is the next step to try out:  `(defun dropbox-get-status () (let ((status (shell-command-to-string "dropbox status"))) (setq status (replace-regexp-in-string "\n$" "" status)) (replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " status)))`  It is non-interactive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37864/discussion-between-jackkamm-and-lawlist).

Comment: I'm working on other projects throughout the day and may not take this particular question all the way through to a formal answer, in which case another forum participant can take over.  In general, I am an anti-chat type of guy because I may need time to formulate a reply.  The timer would take some time to perfect, with a cancel-timer following its initial definition and then a way to activate and deactivate.  A minor-mode dedicated to that would probably be the most appropriate.  Comments leave a breadcrumb trail for everyone to easily follow and take over, or go in a different direction.

Comment: No problem, I simply clicked on "move to chat" because the website recommended it. I was thinking of printing the first line, like `(defun dropbox-get-status () (let ((status (shell-command-to-string "dropbox status"))) (setq status (car (split-string status "\n")))))`, or maybe the first n characters of such. Whether or not you carry through to final answer, thanks for all your help, on my first foray into emacs lisp :) You've given me the tools to solve this myself, though I may not do so today because of other projects as well